# SMBLibrary: "An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions"

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, smb

[SMBLibrary project on GitHub](https://github.com/TalAloni/SMBLibrary) appears to be is exactly what I am looking for.
I need something to abstract a db to look like a file system, accessible via UNC path.

I am using Windows 10, Visual Studio as Administrator. I installed the MS Loopback Adapter, and disabled the other adapters. I have stopped the "Server" service.

Running the  the server on 127.0.0.1, port 445 I receive the following error:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
  HResult=0x80004005
  Message=An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
   at SMBLibrary.Server.SMBServer.Start(IPAddress serverAddress, SMBTransportType transport, Boolean enableSMB1, Boolean enableSMB2, Nullable`1 connectionInactivityTimeout) in C:\Users\josep\Source\Repos\SMBLibrary\SMBLibrary\Server\SMBServer.cs:line 87
```

I am expecting to run the server app, then using explorer navigate to \127.0.0.1

It is not clear from Read.me if this is correct or not.

Comment: Are you running the server as Admin?

Answer (score 0):

The readme is pretty clear on what you are doing wrong:

if you want localhost access from Windows explorer to work as expected, you must specify the IP address that you selected (\127.0.0.1 or \localhost will not work as expected), in addition, I have observed that when connecting to the first IP address of a given adapter, Windows will only attempt to connect to port 445.

You need to connect to the IP address assigned to the loopback adapter.